# Webview submit form when click "Go" button

Tags: android, webview

I'm developing an android app. It uses WebView to load a form with following component:

- Username textbox
- Password textbox
- Submit button

When I fill all fields then click submit button, data will be validated, but when I click "Go" button from android keyboard, nothing happens. How I can resolve it?

P/S: I'm debugging on an android 4.4.4 devices.

Comment: Where is your log? I can't see it

Comment: i think this code will help  android:singleLine="true"

Comment: @SanjuChandran Thanks. But its still not working.

Comment: @Shahzeb My app starts then runs normally. Its has nothing to show.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use html form and javascript to control submit. form submit on Go button click;

```
<form>
      <input type='text' id='user_id' />
      <input type='password' id='password' />
      <input type='button' id='btn_login' />
</form>
<script>
function login()
{
  // login code here
}
$('btn_login').click(function() {
    login();
});
$('form').submit(function() {
    // this event fire on go button click.
    login();
    return false;
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

have a look at https://github.com/dx-luna/loena

javascript

```js
function click(){
   window.go_submit("user88","pass22")
}
```

golang

```golang
webview.Bind("go_submit", func(username string,password string){
  println("user input, username : "+username+" password : "+password)
})
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    For that you need to handle button click event 

    view.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                if ((event != null && (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) || (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE)) {
                    Log.i(TAG,"Enter pressed");
//do whatever you were doing in submit button
                }    
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: I cant find setOnEditorActionListener() method in WebView.

Comment: It should be on the view that contain webview

Comment: Incorrect answer! The question is about WebView element and not EditText.